# Is HTML5 turing complete?

Tags: html, turing-complete

I would like to know if it's possible to do that?

```
<turning>
  <complete />
  <complete />
</turing>
```

Thank you

Comment: I cannot understand your code. What does it have to do with Turing-complete?

Answer (score -2):

Yes and No.

In order to create custom HTML elements, you must use the [`Custom Elements API`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements).
This is only supported in [Chrome 54+](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4696261944934400), and [Safari 10.1+](https://webkit.org/status/#feature-custom-elements).
[Edge](https://twitter.com/AaronGustafson/status/717028669948977153), and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889230) are still working on the feature.